# How to find derivative using Leibniz formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem :

Use the Leibniz formula for computing the following derivative :

$[(x^2+1)sinx]^{(20)}$

Please guide how to solve this.. thanks ..

Comment: You can try using the chain rule which states that $(f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. In you case let $f(x)=x^{20}$ and $g(x)=(x^2+1) \sin(x)$

Comment: Do you know Leibniz's rule? Why don't you start writing it down, and telling us what parts of it you do not understand?

Comment: @user10444 That is not a $20$-th power, but the $20$-th derivative.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the parenthesis. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Applying [Leibniz' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule):
$$
\binom{20}{0}\overbrace{(x^2+1)}^{\text{$0$ derivatives}}\underbrace{\sin(x)}_{\text{$20$ derivatives}}
+\binom{20}{1}\overbrace{2x}^{\text{$1$ derivative}}\underbrace{(-\cos(x))}_{\text{$19$ derivatives}}
+\binom{20}{2}\overbrace{2}^{\text{$2$ derivatives}}\underbrace{(-\sin(x))}_{\text{$18$ derivatives}}
$$
So the answer is
$$
(x^2-379)\sin(x)-40x\cos(x)
$$